# Angular 2,(change) event not firing on bootstrap checkbox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

i have an issue, `(change)` function is not firing in that checkbox.

```
 <input [(ngModel)]="driver.glasses" name="glasses" type="checkbox" class="make-switch"
   (change)="changeFuntion()"  data-on-color="primary" data-off-color="info">
```

But in this one it works

```
    <input [(ngModel)]="driver.glasses" name="glasses" type="checkbox" 
   (change)="changeFuntion()"  data-on-color="primary" data-off-color="info">
```

I have noticed that `class="make-switch"` is the  problem, because in the first checkbox with that class, `(change)` don´t work. How I can solve this, I need to apply `class="make-switch"` to make switch checkbox.

Comment: what does make-switch class has? does it has any events?

Comment: when you are using `[(ngModel)]` go with ng model change `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"`

Comment: make-switch class does  input toggle, and it doesn´t have events.

Comment: I test with  `(ngModelChange)`, but don´t work

Comment: Can you share `make-switch` class?

Comment: have you tried it with providing that class to parent div? something like `<div class="make-switch"><input type="checkbox"></div>` something like that?

Comment: `make-switch` class is from bootstrap, in this page uses that to make check box toggle http://www.jque.re/plugins/version3/bootstrap.switch/, and i try with `<div class="make-switch"><input type="checkbox"></div>`, the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ngModelChange like this :

This is your component.ts

```js
checkboxValue: any;

changeEvent(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="checkboxValue" (ngModelChange)="changeEvent($event)" data-md-icheck/>
```

Comment: Please check the comment over the question. That he has already tried with `ngModelChange` but that does not work.

Comment: code example does not exist in comment , that is why i posted that

Comment: But that is not the correct answer right? As questioner has already mentioned it. He doesn't need code example here. He need solution. And this answer does not provide any.

Comment: my answer is correct and it works everywhere, if he tries that  and that does not work , it means problem is not relating to change event

Comment: My friend check question properly. Check the scenario when it is not working. I know this works for you but for his scenario with class which he has mentioned is not the proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `(ngModelChange)` doesn`t work